# Call a remote API through NodeJS and attach the result to my API fails

Tags: node.js, api

I am trying to call an API from a CA API , that returns the certificate file as attachment in the format p7b. I need to attach the same to my API and return to my client. I am new to NodeJS and I am not able to get this working. Could anybody help?

I have tried res.pipe() , it did not work. I have given below my code snippet.

```
app.get("/api/certificate/:certificateid", function (req, res) {         
        var certificateId = req.params.certificateid;
        var header = {
            "X-DC-DEVKEY": apiKey,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        };
        var options = {
            host: certUrl,
            port: 443,
            method: 'GET',
            path: 'xxxxx/certificate/' + certificateId + '/download/format/p7b',
            headers: header
        };
       https.request(options, function (res1) {
         //   res1.setEncoding('gzip');   DID NOT WORK             
            res1.on('data', function (data) {
                var result = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log(result);                   
                res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-pkcs7-certificates');
                res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
                res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'filename=blockwaveinsurance_com.p7b');
                res.end(data,'gzip');
            });

        }).end();
    });
```

Comment: may i know more  description ur question , like what to send in response from  where you get these ?

Comment: CA API returns certificate as p7b file. I need to return the same from my API. Its a Digicert API , that returns a certificate file.

Comment: use res.json({result:resultl})

Comment: Its a bundle of certificates. I cannot do json it.

Comment: i think for that you have to read and write file using fs.readFile and fs.writeFile()

Comment: No Shekar. It is client certificate, I dont want to store in my system anywhere. All I wanted to just pass the attachment from remote api to my api.  I have provided the working code below. Thanks for responding.

Comment: you don't need to store the certificate , just save the data and remove the file using fs.unlink() thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, https is not working for me to resend the attachment from remote api to my api through pipe or any other way but I was able to to do it through request module. Here is the code if anybody needs it

```
var certUrl='www.xxxx.com';

var apiKey='xxxxx';

 app.get("/api/certificate/:certificateid", function (req, res) 
{

            var certificateId = req.params.certificateid;

            var url=certUrl+"/services/v2/certificate/" + certificateId + "/download/format/p7b"; 

            var options = {
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    "X-DC-DEVKEY": apiKey,
                }
            };

            function callback(error, response, body) {

                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                    console.log('no error');

                }
            }

            request(options, callback).pipe(res);
        });
```